# .Net Core Graph API Token Issue - "Access token has expired or is not yet valid"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, token, openid-connect

I am developing a `.Net 6` application, hosted in an `Azure App Service` and using `Azure AD Authentication`.

When viewing a Request page, I would like to check if the user belongs to an `Azure Ad Group`. This works sometimes, but users will periodically get an error when trying to view the page: "Access token has expired or is not yet valid."

I assume the token is being expired as if the user clears their cookies, AAD will re-authenticate them creating a new token and all is fine again, but  but I haven't been able to find anything around refreshing tokens and am not sure where to go from here.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour and found a solution for it?

Here are some relevant sections of the code

Startup.cs File:

```
        string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("GraphAPI:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
            }, initialScopes)
           .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
           .AddMicrosoftGraph(options =>
           {
               options.Scopes = String.Join(' ', initialScopes);
           });
```

AADGroupFunctions.cs

```
        AADGroupFunctions.cs

        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

        public AADGroupFunctions(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        public async Task<List<IADLookupModel>> FindUsersInGroup(string groupId)
        {
            var listOfUsers = new List<IADLookupModel>();
            var filterString = $"startswith(mail, '{groupId}')";
            var groups = await _graphServiceClient.Groups
                              .Request()
                              .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                              .Filter(filterString)
                              .Expand("members")
                              .Top(1)
                              .GetAsync();

            if (groups.Any())
            {
                if (groups.First().Members.Any())
                {
                    foreach (Microsoft.Graph.User user in groups.First().Members)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var mail = "";
                            if (user.Mail != null)
                            {
                                mail = user.Mail.ToLower();

                                listOfUsers.Add(new UserModel()
                                {
                                    DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                                    UPN = user.UserPrincipalName.ToLower(),
                                    Email = mail,
                                    Description = user.JobTitle ?? ""
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return listOfUsers;
        }
```

Error Message when trying to call the `FindUsersInGroup()` function:

```
            An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. 
        ServiceException: Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken Message: Access token has expired or is not yet valid. Inner error: AdditionalData: date: 2022-02-21T17:37:46 request-id: [removed] client-request-id: [removed] ClientRequestld: [removed] Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
        Routing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token have a short lifetime, sometimes like an hour or even shorter. So you need to use a refresh token to ask AzureAd for a new access token when the current one is about to expire.

see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tore!
I've been searching for a way to do this since you answered yesterday, but as of yet haven't been able to find a way to actually do that.

From my understanding, the .AddMicrosoftGraph function should create an instance of the GraphServiceClient, and handle token refreshing, but sometimes it does, and others it does not. 
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph/MicrosoftGraphExtensions.cs

Do you have any advice on how to refresh the token?

Comment: you need to make sure the client asks for the offline_access scope (that tells the auth server that it should also send a refresh token... But I haven't used GraphServiceClient, so I can't tell....

Comment: Thanks for the extra info - I did some more digging and found some more context around the offline_access scope which may be helpful for others:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access

How to add offline_access scope to the Auth provider
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user?tabs=azure-resource-explorer%2Cprogramming-language-csharp